# stop cursor from blinking on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I've been using Overleaf for four years. The cursor didn't use to blink three months ago. But today when I used Overleaf again, the cursor started blinking, which is very distracting for me. Moreover, I notice that the height of the cursor is smaller that it used to be. I googled how to access the cursor setting but didn't find anything useful.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. The attached is a screenshot of the cursor.
[cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdsSN.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps, it's a Linux/firefox solution but the same principle would apply to other devices and browsers (monospace).

https://superuser.com/questions/1431132/overleaf-text-input-cursor-offset-on-arch-liunux